# How do I beat the dragon in Castle Keep?

Tags: candy-box

In [Candy Box](http://candies.aniwey.net/), How do I beat the dragon at the end of the castle keep level? Even with a Level 2 sword of life, starting the fight with an invincibility buff, and 170hp I'm only getting it down to 700hp.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way I did it seems pretty fool-proof. I just ran in and popped an invulnerability potion right before I touched the boss. Then when it runs out teleport back. When you get to the boss next time, the timer still won't be up though, so you'll have to use another teleport scroll, but then the next time you can turn invincible again, and repeat the strategy until victory. It's pretty costly, but the winnings will pay for it easily.

Comment: One alternative to using two teleport scrolls is to make some Seeds. Use one immediately after Teleporting, and that'll give you some time for your potion cooldown. You can even use an Earthquake or Acid Rain scroll while sitting around to speed things up!

Comment: To get an idea of the costs: With a level 9 flame sword it took me 3 rounds, i.e. 3 invulnerability potions and 6 teleport scrolls.

Comment: You could also try planting a seed in front of yourself on the way back to save another teleport scroll (it takes a while to break the tree), but the teleport scroll is probably cheaper than concocting a seed in the cauldron.

Comment: When I teleport while in the boss room, it just sends me back to the door *still in the boss room*...  Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: I'm pretty sure. It still lets the timer run down.

Answer (score 4):

I guess my way kind of sucked, but I kept eating candies until I got up to around 1000hp myself, then just kept drinking major health potions whenever possible.

Comment: If my math is correct getting to 1k hp would take 3.8024×10^6 candies, which seems a bit extreme for beating that level, compared to the other answer

Comment: 3,802,400 without the scientific notation

Comment: I'm all for scientific notation but @PrivatePansy might want to consider using a shorter form and rounding a bit since their version actually used more symbols than the number written out in full.

Answer (score 1):

invincible, teleport, seed, repeat is the basic way to beat the dragon.
if you have to, use the cloning/seed combo in the cauldron (burn water, 869050/22750/1950 candies, stop, bottle for 650 cloning 1337 seeds/17 cloning 35 seeds/1 cloning 3 seeds)
if you have enough health, you could also clone at beginning, then invincible/fire scroll if needed.

Answer (score 0):

By eating 17 000 000 candies, I had 1755 HP and when in front of the dragon, I just used an invincibility potion, having so much HP let me use another one and by the time I use the 2 potions, the dragon is left with a few HP and I still had 200HP when he died.