# How do I survive the Developper's garden?

Tags: candy-box

Is there a way to limit the damage one constantly takes in Developper's garden? I get killed every time and don't even know by what.

Comment: Editors: It's actually spelled "Developper" (with the double "p") in the game, not "Developer". =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use many invulnerability potions, just before you reach the enemies. Watch the countdown and teleport yourself back, when it's nearly over. Then use a seed or another teleport-scroll, so that you can use another invulnerability potion right before the next enemy. It took me the seeds and teleport-scrolls to finish them.

Comment: I did it that way, and finally got through it. thx

Comment: The reason why you couldn't get through before was that some of the monsters in the Developppppper's Garden are plasma guns that halve your health from afar. By the time you get near them you are in a position to die in 1 hit. However, they are far enough away that you only need to use 1 teleport scroll before your potion timer is recovered to use an invulnerability potion.

Comment: Ah, so it's the same way one can [beat the dragon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116096/88)

Answer (score 0):

I did it by teleporting back before I got to those evil CGs, and always threw around earthquake scrolls on my way. Somehow that seemed to work...